# Spring boot project unable to resolve symbol SpringockitoContextLoader

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I am getting error "   **cant resolve symbol SpringockitoContextLoader**
" on this following line in test package

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringockitoContextLoader.class ....
```

I have migrated to spring 2.0.3 , I am suspecting SpringockitoContextLoader is not used anymore

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean "Spring Boot" when you say "spring 2.0.3", you should use [Spring Boot Test's built-in support for mocks and spies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans) via `@MockBean` and `@SpyBean` instead of [Springockito](https://github.com/springockito/springockito) (which is a separate project that resides outside the official Spring portfolio).